# OS Vectormap GML files into PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, vector, gml

I am having difficulty in efficiently dealing with OS Vectormap data that comes in GML format. 
In the past I used the Plugin for QGIS (OS GML Tools) to batch convert folders of compressed GML (.GZ) to shapefiles which are then merged and added to the QGIS as a layer. As I now have a lot more data (~150 GML files) and using Shapefiles directly loaded into QGIS is a very slow and inefficient way of displaying/editing the data I have decided to get the data loaded into a PostGIS database.

The first issue is that the plugin doesn't seem to work. When I choose an input folder with only .GZ files (For Example - Vectormap/SP) and then pick the output as an empty folder I created (Vectormap/SP Shapefiles) the process runs and completes but fills the folder with shapefiles only a 1kb in size. When loaded into QGIS these shapefiles appear to do nothing. I have uninstalled the plugin and re-installed to no avail.

If anyone has a better or alternative suggestion for getting GML files into a PostGIS database then I would appreciate it. Surely there musty be an easier way for people using Open Source GIS software to load in Ordnance Survey Vector data?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give Loader from Astun Technology a go. Its open source and is available through their github site [here.](https://github.com/AstunTechnology/Loader)

The Ordnance survey actually use it themselves to load the data for their OnDemand Web Map Service

It has a few dependencies and is mostly command line driven but is very effective. I've used it to load a variety of GML datasets (90+ files) including OS Mastermap and Vector Map Local into Postgis.